# I have add export plugin and I am getting error model 'portal 'not availble

Tags: angularjs

I am using export table plugin 
    https://github.com/Epotignano/angular-export-table.
I have added the module "portal" but I am getting an error

- Module 'portal'not available
  I have added dependency but I am getting same error.
- This is my dependency code

  ```
  (function () {

  angular.module('portal', [
  'ui.router',
  'ceibo.components.table.export',
  'portal']);
  })();
  and smart table plugin code is

  (function(){
  angular.module('portal')
  .directive('stFilteredCollection', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^stTable',
        scope: {
          stFilteredCollection: '='
        },
        controller: 'stTableController',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
          scope.$watch(function () {
            return ctrl.getFilteredCollection();
          }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            scope.stFilteredCollection = ctrl.getFilteredCollection();
          });
        }
      };
  });    })();
  ```

  please let me know what is my mistake.

Comment: If you think that given answer is correct then please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you aren't loading your modules correctly. In your code you need to remove **`portal`** from attempting to use itself as a dependency when creating the `portal` module. See the comment below.

```
angular.module('portal', [ 
  'ui.router',
  'ceibo.components.table.export',
  'portal']); //REMOVE THIS 
})();
```